# linker on debian does not see symlined shared libs

Tags: linker, debian, eclipse-cdt, linker-errors, openscenegraph

I have got this error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibosg

while GCC C++ Linker invoked with:

```
g++ -i -L/home/user/osg/lib -o"WCC"  [my files] -llibosg -llibOpenThreads -llibosgQt -llibosgViewer -llibosgText
```

command locate libosg.so returns:

```
/home/user/osg/lib/libosg.so
/home/user/osg/lib/libosg.so.3.1.3
/home/user/osg/lib/libosg.so.92
/usr/lib/libosg.so.28.3
/usr/lib/libosg.so.65
/usr/local/lib/libosg.so
/usr/local/lib/libosg.so.3.1.3
/usr/local/lib/libosg.so.92
```

I've switched from Win, where everything works fine. I'm using Eclipse. Why linker doesn't see those libraries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be `-losg`? Remove the lib part from all the -ls.

Comment: OK, that was it, thanks (on Win those libs, where with lib- and it works)